# Criterion for vanishing of Hom sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module which is supported in a proper subscheme $Y$ of $X$ in the sense that $Y$ is of codimension at least $1$ in $X$. We know that if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is torsion free then the $\mathcal{H}om$-sheaf $\mathcal{H}om_X(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X)$ is zero. Is there any alternative condition on $\mathcal{O}_X$ under which the vanishing of the $\mathcal{H}om$ sheaf still holds?